# Could a 130 volt bulb have overloaded a lamp specifying 120v bulbs?

Tags: electrical, light-bulb

I had a floor lamp burst into fire from one of the lights. I don't think it was the lightbulb - it seemed like it was the wiring, but honestly I'm not sure. I was checking now to see if perhaps the wrong light bulb was in the lamp. I saw that although the lamp requires a 120 volt bulb I think the bulb in there was 130 volt. Could this have caused the problem?
The pictures show where the fire was. I was able to turn the lamp off right away, but when it was burning it was like a torch coming out of there. If there were curtains nearby, they almost certainly would have caught.
[image]

. [image]

Comment: Actually, quite the opposite. The 130v bulb was designed for higher voltage, therefore it actually runs a bit cooler at "only" 120v. TBH, you'll probably need a fire investigator to find where the fire actually started - not sure if we have one of those lurking about here. At a minimum, you'd need to post some pics of what's left of the lamp for anyone to have a chance of making an _educated_ guess about it. Without pics, they'll just be _uneducated_ guesses.

Comment: The bulb wattage is the important number to know.  A 100w bulb in a 40w max lamp is usually bad.  A 130v bulb is usually just a more robust bulb compared to a 120v bulb.

Comment: As a guess, what probably happen was that one or more electrical connections between the bulb and socket and wires, became loose, causing more resistance and excessive heating.

Comment: I bet the wire terminations on the back of that socket were done poorly or their insulation failed, leading them to short out against eachother.

Comment: @BillyC. If this is true it would be a problem with the lamp or with the wall socket?

Comment: Lamp.  There is no way the outlet could cause this

Comment: @BillyC. Thanks. Excuse my ignorance :)

Comment: The pattern of damage shown in the photos suggests that the fire was at the rim of the shade, some distance from anything electrical, but at the point where rising heat from a grossly over-wattage bulb would concentrate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pretty much rule out the bulb as the culprit unless the wattage of the bulbs exceeded  the labeled maximum for the floor lamp. What usually happens then is the wires feeding the socket become toast and short out causing a short circuit and possibly tripping a breaker.

Examine all the wiring in the lamp with a continuity tester or just junk it and get a new one if you're not familiar with re wiring a lamp. If it's a keepsake item you can bring it to an appliance repair store and they'll rewire it.

Comment: I just threw it out, and will buy a new one. Thanks for the answer!